# SwiftUI conditional causing an MVVM view's navigationTitle to not update

Tags: ios, swiftui

Here's a hypothetical master/detail pair of SwiftUI views that presents a button which uses `NavigationLink:value:label:` to navigate to a child view. The child view uses MVVM and has a `.navigationTitle` modifier that displays a placeholder until the real value is set (by a network operation that is omitted for the sake of brevity).

Upon first launch, tapping the button does navigate to the child view, but the "Loading child..." navigationTitle placeholder never changes to the actual value of "Alice" despite being set in the viewmodel's `loadChild()` method. If you navigate back and tap the button *again*, all subsequent navigations do set the navigationTitle correctly.

However, the child view has an `if` condition. If that `if` condition is replaced with `Text("whatever")` and the app is re-built and re-launched, the navigationTitle gets set properly *every time*. Why does the presence of an `if` condition inside the view affect the setting of the view's navigationTitle, and only on the *first* use of navigation?

```swift
import SwiftUI

// MARK: Data Structures
struct AppDestinationChild: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
}

struct Child: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

// MARK: -
struct ChildView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: ChildViewModel

    init(id: Int) {
        vm = ChildViewModel(id: id)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            // Replacing this `if` condition with just some Text()
            // view makes the navigationTitle *always* set properly,
            // including during first use.
            if vm.pets.count <= 0 {
                Text("No pets")
            } else {
                Text("List of pets would go here")
            }
        }
            .navigationTitle(vm.child?.name ?? "Loading child...")
            .task {
                vm.loadChild()
            }
    }
}

// MARK: -
extension ChildView {
    @MainActor class ChildViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var id: Int
        @Published var child: Child?
        @Published var pets = [String]()

        init(id: Int) {
            self.id = id
        }

        func loadChild() {
            // Some network operation would happen here to fetch child details by id
            self.child = Child(id: id, name: "Alice")
        }
    }
}

// MARK: -
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink(value: AppDestinationChild(id: 42), label: {
                Text("Go to child view")
            })
            .navigationDestination(for: AppDestinationChild.self) { destination in
                ChildView(id: destination.id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change to StateObject

Comment: That works! In the ChildView init I changed the VM creation to `_vm = StateObject(wrappedValue: ChildViewModel(id: id))`. Reading up on StateObject vs ObservedObject is enlightening. If you post an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The point of `.task` is to get rid of the need for a reference type for async code, I recommend you replace your state object with state, e.g.

```
        @State var child: Child?

        .task {
            child = await Child.load()
        }
```

You could also catch an exception and have another state for an error message.

Comment: Hmm. Child is just a data model struct. Should it also be responsible for populating itself?

Comment: A static func on the model type is just an idea but can put the async func anywhere you like, e.g. a static func in the View or in an extension of NSURLSession is another idea.